# How to delete specific node by attribute from XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am novice and struggling in some XML operations Like open and Delete. I have done the Add part.

Partys.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Partys>
  <Customers>
    <Customer CustomerID="1">
      <PersonalName>
        <LastName>Baker</LastName>
        <FirstName>Eugene</FirstName>
      </PersonalName>
      <Citizenship>Africa</Citizenship>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerID="2">
      <PersonalName>
        <LastName>Baker</LastName>
        <FirstName>Eugene</FirstName>
      </PersonalName>
      <Citizenship>Africa</Citizenship>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
 </Partys>
```

Q: I want to open the node detail customer where CustomerID (Attribute) is 1. What is the C# code for this?

Q: I want to delete the node customer where CustomerID (Attribute) is 2. What is the C# code for this?

Comment: What is an "`Open`" operation? Like in a visual tree view, expanding the child nodes?!?

Comment: You might find this link useful:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Comment: Sorry for being Vague. By Open I tried to indicate show that node detail in the console. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: Thank you, John - for the correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Parties.xml");
XmlNode t = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Partys/Customers/Customer[@CustomerID='2']");
t.ParentNode.RemoveChild(t);
xmlDoc.Save();
```

Once you have t, you can do whatever you want with it including show it in the Console (by accessing the various properties)

Here, we have deleted the node and saved back to file, but you could do whatever you want with the XmlDocument....

Comment: Once more, what is the right way to pass a parameter in SelectSinglenode?                                                   int ID;                                                             XmlNode t = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Partys/Customers/Customer[@CustomerID='2']");                                                 How can I send the 'ID' in place of '2'?     Thanks Again.

Comment: int ID = 2;
            XmlNode customersNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Partys/Customers/Customer[@CustomerID=' " + ID + " ' ]");
            customersNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(customersNode);
            xDoc.Save(@"..\\Partys.xml");                                                      it is showing : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  any clue?